# How to automatically close window after execution?

Tags: c

How can I close the command window in C ? `exit(-1)` doesnt work , it just returns `-1` . I want the window to close without pressing any key . I'm using CodeBlocks in Win 8.1.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   Commands();
   exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Which window ? The terminal one ?

Comment: The one that opens when i run the code from CodeBlocks

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: There may be some special provision in CodeBlocks that allows you to do this, but in general this is not possible. C programs are run as child processes of the shell environment (e.g., `bash`), and cannot force it to quit.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1  .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is windows as you said command window, not terminal? Have you tried [FreeConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

If you open the console from windows and run your app inside it, then you cannot close it, because the console only closes when all processes which share it detach... and the windows process which created the console would still be attached.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make the CodeBlocks window close after execution , but it seems that if i execute the code from command line it closes after execution . Thanks.